# Function theme_enqueue_styles() for child css

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, parent-child

My folder for my child themes is well composed of a file 'style.css' and 'functions.php'
In my functions.php file I can not access my function theme_enqueue_styles() to use my custom css

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() .'/style.css' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the child theme, you need to replace `get_template_directory_uri()` to `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.

The code should be:.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/style.css' );
}
```